# Is <a> essential in: played hide-and-seek with <a> child’s eyes

Tags: indefinite-article

> My earliest childhood memory is of the swaying limbs of Golden Delicious 
>   apple trees. Rows of them stood next to a dirt road that separated our
>   orchard from the front yard.
>
> The Kentucky summer sky hung hot behind those high twigs, their leaves
>   leathery green on top, soft as down underneath.
>
> The apples, little bigger than shooter marbles then, *played hide-and-seek with **a child’s eyes**.*

Frank Browning,“Sweet Temptation,” Reader’s Digest

If the apples swing around in the air like a child's eyes do. Would not the prepositional phrase be put without the indefinite article *a* as follows:

> *played hide-and-seek with **child’s eyes**.*

rather than

> *played hide-and-seek with **a child’s eyes**.*

Think of:

> I go by bus

not

> I go by a bus

To me, saying:
 "*played hide-and-seek with **a child’s eyes***" is much like there are *two parties* playing hide-and-seek: the apples, and a child's eyes.

Comment: By *"To me, saying: 'played hide-and-seek with a child’s eyes' is much like there are 'two parties' playing hide-and-seek: the apples and a child's eyes."*, do you mean a) [the apples and a child] 's eyes, or b) the apples and [ a child's eyes ]?

Comment: b. However, how could *a* be possible?

Comment: I didn't think a) really make sense, but then again, if you meant b), which you did, the whole sentence didn't make sense to me because it didn't add or clarify anything in the question when I read it (so I guessed, maybe you parsed it another way). "[The apple] played hide-and-seek with a child’s eyes" is not only much like there are two parties playing hide-and-seek (the apples and the eyes of the author), it's exactly so. It's just used figuratively in the narrative (i.e., the apples were personified).

Answer (score 1):

> The apples, little bigger than shooter marbles then, played hide-and-seek with a child’s eyes.

There are indeed two parties playing hide-and-seek here:

The first party is the apples. The second party is the young Frank Browning.

It is partially a descriptive phrase. He is describing himself as "a child" in the sentence, and simultaneously says that some of the apples were hidden by the limbs or by the leaves, and "played hide-and-seek" with that child.

Of course, a child uses his eyes to look at the apples as they appear and disappear, so "the apples played hide-and-seek with a child's eyes".

Compare:

> I started working as a [breaker boy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breaker_boy) in 1880. That was a tough work for **me**. (the author refers to himself directly: "me")
>
> I started working as a [breaker boy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breaker_boy) in 1880. That was a tough work for **a kid of 12**. (he describes himself as "a kid of 12")

---

P.S. There's a fancy-pants linguistic term that could be used to describe "a child's eyes" here: [synecdoche](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synecdoche).